# Populate Cellset using Objects

Tags: c#, ado.net, mdx, adomd.net

I have been working with MDX and cellset in recent times. I was given a MDX query which can show up the data in 3 dim format and I able to get the data using CELLSET in .Net code. Later I am converting the cellset to datatable to make it lot easier to manipulate and display in the application. (similiar to the code from : http://asmdx.blogspot.in/2008/05/code-utility-code-for-converting.html )

I was just wondering why do I need to use Datatable which eats up considerable amount of memory.. I got to think of replacing the datatable with Objects. i.e., **Converting a Cellset to   a collection of user defined objects.**. Is tat possible? Any help please ?

Answer (score 2):

You could get the MDX query results in a XML format using the [ExecuteXmlReader method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123462.aspx) of ADOMD.NET: your memory problems would be solved, and then you could with (relative) ease consume the resulting XML in your application (you could, for instance, use Linq for XML to transform the XML into business objects).